# listview not running screen crashes everytime I run

Tags: android, listview

I want to display a list using listview my following code not running
following is xml and java files of my code in xml I have used only a listview.

main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ListView
       android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="435dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ListView.java

```
package com.example.lisst;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListView extends ListActivity {
    ListView listview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String[] values = new String[] { "Visual Basic", "C#", "C/C++",
    "PHP", "Foxpro", "Delphi", "Java", "Perl",
    "Ruby", "Cobol" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to declare ListView in your AndroidManofest.xml. You should also change tools:context=".MainActivity" to tools:context=".ListView" if you use your layout for ListView;

If you will provide stacktrace I will be able to give you more proper answer